# Refactoring fields of anonymous unions using clang lib

Tags: c++, c, refactoring, llvm-clang

I'm doing a small refactoring tool to assist me with some automated C code generation and I'm using clang API for that. I developed a tool that works with all but one specific test case:

```
typedef int mytype;
typedef float mytype2;

union ab
{
    mytype a;
    mytype2 b;
};  

int fun(int);

int foo(mytype bar)
{   
        return fun( ((union{ mytype a; mytype2 b; })bar).a );
}
```

In this code I want to refactor the "mytype" occurrences to a new "mytype3", the way I'm doing this is creating a TypeLoc AST Matcher ( typeLoc().bind("id") ) to find all the types and replace them with a RefactoringTool (standard refactoring procedure found everywhere on the internet). But for this specific case the AST doesn't seem to contain the definition for the anonymous union being used to do the casting, I dumped the AST using XClang:

```
`-FunctionDecl 0x6b757f0 <line:12:1, line:15:1> line:12:5 foo 'int (mytype)'
  |-ParmVarDecl 0x6b75730 <col:9, col:16> col:16 bar 'mytype':'int'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x6b75bb0 <line:13:1, line:15:1>
    `-ReturnStmt 0x6b75b90 <line:14:2, col:53>
      `-CallExpr 0x6b75b60 <col:9, col:53> 'int'
        |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x6b75b48 <col:9> 'int (*)(int)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
        | `-DeclRefExpr 0x6b75898 <col:9> 'int (int)' Function 0x6b2f790 'fun' 'int (int)'
        `-MemberExpr 0x6b75af0 <col:14, col:51> 'mytype':'int' .a 0x6b75970
          `-ParenExpr 0x6b75ad0 <col:14, col:49> 'union (anonymous union at unions.c:14:16)':'union (anonymous at unions.c:14:16)'
            `-CStyleCastExpr 0x6b75aa8 <col:15, col:46> 'union (anonymous union at unions.c:14:16)':'union (anonymous at unions.c:14:16)' <ToUnion>
              `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x6b75a90 <col:46> 'mytype':'int' <LValueToRValue>
                `-DeclRefExpr 0x6b75a18 <col:46> 'mytype':'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x6b75730 'bar' 'mytype':'int'
```

And in fact it appears to ignore the body of the union completely. So is it there a solution for this "problem", or at least an alternative for this refactoring?

As an alternative I tried to enumerate the fields of the anonymous union from the RecordDecl object, but I couldn't find how.

Thank you.